# Como concatenar variável php para passar como parâmetro

Tags: php

Preciso deletar registros vindo do meu banco de dados mas não estou conseguindo passar a variável para efetuar a operação, não estou conseguindo concatenar a variável no meu código, fiz o seguinte:

```
$aretorno["tabela"] .=  '<td align="center"><button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" onclick="DlgExcluirNota($IdFase)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title="Excluir nota"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td> ';
```

A mensagem no meu console é essa:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $IdFase is not defined
onclick @ DetalhesContrato.php:1
```

O Id existente no banco é 192.

Comment: A variável `$IdFase` é do PHP, certo?

Comment: Olá @KaduAmaral, isso mesmo, é uma variável do php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o "\" para intercalar as aspas, para que a concatenação seja feita:

```
$aretorno["tabela"] .=  "<td align=\"center\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" aria-hidden=\"true\" onclick=\"DlgExcluirNota($IdFase)\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"auto\" title=\"Excluir nota\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></td>";
```

Comment: Baill, rapaz, desculpa, depois de tanto tempo venho agradecer a grande ajuda, valeu.

Answer (score 3):

No PHP existem algumas formas de encapsular *strings* as principais são usando a `"string"` (aspas duplas) e também `'string'` (aspas simples) e elas não são a mesma coisa.

A aspa dupla faz uma busca na string pra ver se tem alguma expressão ali dentro, inclusive variáveis. Já a aspa simples interpreta a string como literal e tudo sairá conforme foi escrito.

**Exemplos:**

```
$nome1 = 'Carlos';
$nome2 = 'Eduardo';
echo 'Olá $nome1!'; 
// Olá $nome1!

echo "Oi $nome2!";
// Oi Eduardo!

echo 'Meu nome é $nome1.\nE o seu?';
// Meu nome é $nome1.\nE o seu?

echo "O meu?\nÉ $nome2.";
// O meu?
// É Eduardo.
```

Note que usando aspas simples o carácter especial `\n` que representa uma quebra de linha, também não é interpretado. Já nas aspas duplas tanto os carácteres especiais quanto variáveis foram interpretadas corretamente.

**Obs.:** O tempo de execução de *strings* com `"` (aspa dupla) é um pouco maior do que a `'` (aspa simples), devido o PHP lê-la para interpreta-la. Por isso sempre que possível dê preferência para `'` (aspa simples).

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente explicação e código, valeu mesmo @KaduAmaral.